# where to store gradle dependency versions

Tags: android, gradle, properties

I have looked online and come across two different ways of storing the gradle versions for an android app.  One is the `gradle.properties` and the other is the root `build.gradle` file under an ext object.  Both of these are accessible from all other modules.  I am just trying to figure out the difference between each and which one is recommended to use and why?

build.gradle

```
ext {
    versionName = "1.10.10"
    androidGradleTools = "3.4.1"
    compileSdkVersion = 29
    minSdkVersion = 23
    targetSdkVersion = 29
    versionCode = 2
    appCompat = "1.1.0-rc01"
    archCore = "2.0.1"
    material = "1.1.0-alpha09"
    kotlinVersion = "1.3.31"
    kotlinExtensions = "1.1.0-rc01"
    constraintLayout = "1.1.3"
    awsAuth = "2.7.4"
    coordinatorLayout = "1.1.0-beta01"
    eventBus = "3.1.1"
    jUnit = "4.13-beta-3"
    testRunner = "1.2.0"
    espressoCore = "3.2.0"
    annotation = "1.1.0"
    lifecycleViewModel = "2.2.0-alpha02"
    lifecycleExtensions = "2.2.0-alpha02"
    roomVersion = "2.1.0"
    retrofit = "2.6.0"
    okHttp3 = "4.0.0"
    firebaseCommon = "11.4.2"
    crashlytics = "2.10.1"
    slf4Android = "0.1.5"
    butterknife = "10.1.0"
    rabbitMQ = "4.11.1"
    picasso = "2.5.2"
    gson = "2.8.5"
    javaPusher = "1.8.2"
    androidVolley = "1.0.19"
    multidex = "2.0.0"
    googlePlayCore = "1.6.1"
    volley = "1.0.19"
    navController = "2.2.0-alpha01"
    kotlinCoroutines = "1.1.1"
    ktor_version = "1.2.3"
    asyncHttp = "1.4.9"
}
```

gradle.properties

```
# Dependent library versions
android_google_gson_version=2.7
android_google_play_core_version=1.4.1
eventbus_version=3.0.0
squareup_retrofit2_version=2.1.0
squareup_ok_http_version=3.3.1
network_ok_http_logging_interceptor=3.3.1
aws_sdk_auth_core_version=2.7.4
fb_stetho_version=1.5.0
fb_sdk_version=4.37.0
picasso_lib_version=2.5.2
crashlytics_lib_version=2.9.4@aar
volley_lib_version=1.0.19
butterknife_lib_version=8.8.1
commons_io_lib_version=2.4
simbio_encryption_lib_version=1.2.0
anko_common_lib_version=0.8.3
slf_4_android_logger_version=0.1.5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would advise you to store your version numbers in the `ext {}` block. it just stands for "extra properties" which you define.

Why should you not use the gradle.properties? 
Well if we take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties) we can see that gradle.properties should be a file consisting of more "abstract" properties your project needs. Things like Java home or enabling / disabling Gradles caching. In Android we furthermore have the `local.properties` file, which for example declares the path to the Android Sdk.

So these types of properties deal with your project on a different level than declaring dependencies.

Therefore I would advise you to go with the ext block for declaring dependency versions. [This is also what the Android documentation recommends.](https://developer.android.com/studio/build#module-level)

Answer (score 1):

So in gradle 8 there is [better way](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html). Simply create libs.versions.toml file in the gradle folder in your root project. The example file

```
[versions]
spring-boot = "3.1.3"
[plugins]
spring-boot = {id="org.springframework.boot", version.ref="spring-boot"}
[libraries]
spring-boot-jpa = { module = "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa", version.ref = "spring-boot" }
```

And then in your build.gradle to apply plugin you write

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.spring.boot)
}
```

And to add module in dependency block

```
dependencies {
    implementation(libs.spring.boot.jpa)
}
```

You can also get version from the toml file like.

```
libs.versions.spring.boot.get()
```

Which will give you string representing version number.
In order to use it in allprojects or subprojects scope you have to refer to the rootProject like this (kotlin DSL):

```
allprojects {
    ...
    dependencies {
        implementation(rootProject.libs.spring.boot.jpa)
    }
    ...
}
```